# Behavior of C bug: passing pointer to array instead of array into function

Tags: arrays, c, implicit-conversion, function-call, firmware

I recently came across a bug in my C firmware, in which I passed the wrong type into the function. It raises a warning, but I want to understand what could happen in this scenario. During debugging, it works normally (i.e. nothing bad happens), but I want to understand if that could change depending on memory layout.

`uint8_t devinfo[4] = {0}; spi_read_bytes(&devinfo, 4, ADXL362_REG_DEVID_AD);`

Where that function is defined:
`static void spi_read_bytes(uint8_t * data, uint8_t len, uint8_t reg)`

All 4 bytes of devinfo are modified within that function.

In this, I should have passed in "devinfo" or "&devinfo[0]". But what happens if I leave it as is?

Comment: You should remove the ampersand: `spi_read_bytes(devinfo, 4, ADXL362_REG_DEVID_AD);` because the array decays to a pointer. If the array had been supplied as a function argument it would be even more wrong to use `&` which would give the location of the pointer on the stack instead of the array (even if the function argument is defined as an array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the array declaration

```
uint8_t devinfo[4] = {0};
```

the expression `&devinfo` has the pointer type `uint8_t ( * )[4]`. But the function expects an argument of the type `uint8_t *`.

```
static void spi_read_bytes(uint8_t * data, uint8_t len, uint8_t reg);
```

So the compiler issues a warning because there is no implicit conversion between the pointer types..

The code is working because the expression `&devinfo` has the same value as the expression `devinfo` (that is implicitly converted to the type `uint8_t *`) used as an argument of the function call. The both pointers store the value of the address of the first element of the array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @vlad-from-moscow! I understand the mismatch in the inputs, but my main question is - is there any case, as written, in which this mistake would cause unexpected results? I'm searching for a phantom bug in my system and trying to determine if this could possibly be the cause. My understanding from your answer is that, although it is incorrectly written and should be updated, it shouldn't cause issues. Is that correct?

Comment: @JakeWachlin Yes, it shouldn't be a reason of the bug in this particular case of calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

The type that the `&` operator returns is a pointer type. In this case, it is a pointer to an array[4] of `uint_8`, or `uint8_t (*)[4]`, which is not compatible with `uint8_t *`. Hence the warning.

Removing the `&` will resolve it because an array decays to a pointer in function parameters.